# How to access localStorage information with javascript and devtool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm logged into the discord.com page, I would like to know what javascript code I should run to access my email that is in local storage, I tried to run

```
localStorage.getItem("email_cache")
```

but I get the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
```

But if I open devtools in the `applications` tab I see my email in localStorage, how can I access it with javascript?

Comment: It looks like discord.com has done `delete window.localStorage;` for some reason. They probably renamed it to something else first.

Comment: If you have DevTools open, why can't you just use the Storage tab instead of the console?

Comment: You can try to figure out if they've given it a new name that you can access, and use that. But it could be inside a closure, so it's difficult to access. They must be intentionally trying to make this hard for people like you to do.

Comment: @Barmar Because I'm using Selenium to automate the process and using the console tab is the easiest for me, I already have the code to manipulate the console, but I wanted to get it with javascript

Comment: Just did ⌘F 'localStorage' for every single JS file. They deleted `window` and `document`. Can't change anything with those gone. They even name variables like e, r, f so I don't have any idea what they mean. Probably for security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed, as @Barmar suggested, they are renaming the localStorage object inside a closure and then deleting the global reference to it, for security reasons obviously.

This is done in a script called `/assets/89354aa0051558f7225a.js` which is loaded near the end of the `<head>` section.

```
var r;
try {
  r = window.localStorage
} catch (e) {}
try {
  delete window.localStorage
} catch (e) {}
```

The solution is to inject a script at the top of the `<head>` (before any other scripts), to save a reference to the localStorage object to another name so that it can be used later. Since you didn't specify how you're using Selenium I can't give further advise on that, but there are proxies and other ways to get that done.

Side note: I've written and used [this function](https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/ec8cb13162f148559a4d0ae463cd7f2d) in the browser console to search the Discord source code.